# Why say "PC vs Macs"

Tags: etymology

What's the origin of the pharsing since Macs are personal computers and PC stands for Personal Computers but is used to refer to windows-powered computers? I apologise if I used the wrong tag.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably find the answer yourself with some googling. I got this from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-call-computers-MAC-and-PC-while-PC-means-personal-computer-and-both-are-personal-computers) after looking for about a minute:

> The original IBM personal computer was branded as an IBM PC, so the
>   personal computers were either IBM PCs or IBM compatibles.  But, over
>   time IBM lost market share (or, more accurately the market grew and
>   IBM didn't).  At that point "IBM compatible" meant less and they
>   became "PCs".  While the original meaning of PC was "personal
>   computer" it became synonymous for "IBM compatible" meaning it could
>   run DOS (and later Windows.)

Comment: It should probably be noted that at the time the distinction was first made, Macs used Motorola CPUs, not Intel/AMD. Different architecture, different instruction set.